# Set specific IP or name for my docker machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way to set either the IP or ideally a ID and hostname in my hosts file in my docker-compose.yml file? At the moment I'm SSH'ing into my docker DB via SequelPro, but if I start up more than one machine I get different IP's which I then need to update in SequelPro every time.

Ideally I cant to be able to `docker-compose up -d` and then be able to visit myproject.domain.com straight off without having to find the allocated IP each time and change my host file or worry about the allocated IP being different.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options; which one is best really depends on your particular needs.  You say that you are connecting to your container via SSH, but this sounds like a workaround for something: presumably, your Docker container is offering some sort of useful service other than ssh, and that's what you actually need to access.

The easiest solution is simply to expose the network port for that service on your host using the [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ports) directive in your `docker-compose.yaml` file.  If you just need access locally, you can do something like:

```
ports:
  - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
```

That would expose container port 8001 as port 8001 on your local host.  If you need external access to the service (that is, access from some place other than the docker host), you could expose the port on a host interface:

```
ports:
  - "8001:8001"
```

In that case, you could access the service as `<your_host_name_or_ip>:8001`.

If this doesn't meet your needs, there are solutions out there that will register container names in DNS, but I haven't used one recently enough to make a suggestion.